# fadeIn(),fadeOut() in javascript don't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fadein

I want to use fadeIn and fadeOut in javascript in my webpage;but it doesn't work;
it is my code;can you say me where is the problem?it doesn't fadeIn and fadeOut at all!!!

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

$("#DropDownList1").each(function () {

                $('ListItem', this).each(function () {

                    if ($(this).attr("selected") == true)

                        if (($(this).text() != "a")) {

                            $("div#select").fadeOut();
                                                  }
                        else {
                            $("div#select").fadeIn();

                        }
                });
            });
});
```

this is my dropdown list:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="m">a</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="m1">b</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

this is my actual html:

```
<td class="style5" width="20%">
situation:&nbsp;
<br>
<select id="DropDownList1" name="DropDownList2">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="m">a</option>
<option value="m1">b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should look at the actual HTML that the browser sees (not the ASP template code) because I don't think jQuery sees a `ListItem` in the HTML.  Standard dropdowns in HTML are `<option>` tags.  Your ASP might be generating that or something else.

Comment: you mean I sould only change the ListItem in my javascript to option???

Comment: No, I mean you should do a View/Source in the browser and look at what the HTML actually is and code your jQuery to that.  `$('ListItem', this)` probably isn't finding anything.  You should pretty much never go by the ASP code when writing jQuery to operate on it.  You need to know what the browser actually sees after the ASP template has been turned into regular HTML.

Comment: yes;you are right;I used firebug and see that it is option not ListItem!!!!

Comment: also you should something like `$('#DropDownList1').find(":selected")`

Comment: I have changed it to option;but it didn't work again!!!@btefik I have changed the ($this).atrr to $(this).find(":selected") is it true? do you mean that?

Comment: Show us the relevant part of the actual generated HTML from View/Source in the browser (paste it into your question).  We can't help further without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer...

You should look at the actual HTML that the browser sees (not the ASP template code) because I don't think jQuery sees a ListItem in the HTML. Standard dropdowns in HTML are `<option>` tags. Your ASP might be generating that or something else.

Do a View/Source in the browser and look at the HTML that the browser actually sees and code your jQuery to that. `$('ListItem', this)` probably isn't finding anything. You should pretty much never go by the ASP code when writing jQuery to operate on it. You need to know what the browser actually sees after the ASP template has been turned into regular HTML.

FYI, a simplified version of your code that also runs any time the drop down list selection is changed works like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function checkDropDownList() {
        if ($("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text() != "a") {
           $("#select").fadeOut();
        } else {
            $("#select").fadeIn();
        }
    }

    checkDropDownList();

    $("#DropDownList1").change(checkDropDownList);

});
```

There's no reason to use `.each()` if there can only be one selected item and we already know there's only one `DropDownList1`.

Comment: @sarahsh - Show us the relevant part of the actual generated HTML from View/Source in the browser (paste it into your question). We can't help further without that.  I also posted a much simpler version of the code.

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: @sarahsh - Why is the id in your code sample `"DropDownList2"`, but the id in your code is `"DropDownList1"`?  That would keep the code from working.

Comment: no;it's a mistake;my tow ids are the same,but I have try your code and it fade out my div befor any selction of drodownlist and when I change the selection it doesn't show any thing!!!! i think we should write a code witch change the fade as we change the selection in our webpage!

Comment: @jfriend00-thank you so much for your good answers , I think  my javascript code only execute for the first time in page loading;can you say me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @sarahsh - Your code is only written to run once when the page first loads.  If you want it to execute on other events, you have to call it on other events.  I've updated my answer to also trigger the code when the selection is changed by the user.